# Picking a variable's category from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python seaborn library's tips dataset. I am trying to find sum, min, max and mean of "total_bill" according to "time" variable's categories(Dinner and Lunch).

```
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
df.head()

   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     2
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     4
```

```
df.groupby(["time"]).agg({"total_bill":["sum","min", "max" ,"mean"]})
```

This gives the output below. How can i change it to only pick Dinner?

```
       total_bill                        
              sum   min    max       mean
time                                     
Lunch     1167.47  7.51  43.11  17.168676
Dinner    3660.30  3.07  50.81  20.797159
```

I've tried the one below but it gave me "Dinner" as True and "Lunch" as False

```
df.groupby(df["time"]=="Dinner").agg({"total_bill":["sum","min", "max" ,"mean"]})
     

                 total_bill                        
             sum   min    max       mean
time                                    
False    1167.47  7.51  43.11  17.168676
True     3660.30  3.07  50.81  20.797159
```

Comment: `df[df['time']=='Dinner'].groupby("time").agg({"total_bill":["sum","min", "max" ,"mean"]})`

Comment: What do you want to do? you want to select the result for `Dinner`?

Comment: read pandas indexing : [pandas_indexing_user_guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)  you can do boolean indexing before groupby or indexing after groupby